# NiFi's PutHDFS, Custom File Name based on content

Tags: apache-nifi

In NiFi, PutHDFS processor is used to ingest data into HDFS directory. There are 100+ variants of file types possible (all in json format). The json starts with file type. This file type should be made the file name prefix. How to achieve this? Please advise.

```
{
"FILE_TYPE_1": [
        {
                "ORG_FIELD_1" : 38,
                "ORG_FIELD_2" : 1,
                "ORG_FIELD_3" : "Per Km",
                "ORG_FIELD_4" : "x1",
                "ORG_FIELD_5" : 1,
                "ORG_FIELD_6" : 10.0,
                "ORG_FIELD_7" : 0.0,
                "ORG_FIELD_8" : 0.0,
                "ORG_FIELD_9" : 96.0,
                "ORG_FIELD_10" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please show an example json so we can see where the file type comes from

Comment: Updated with example json. As per this json, the file name derived should be "FILE_TYPE_1_<timestamp>"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EvaluateJsonPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) to retrieve the name prefix to attribut then use [UpdateAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html) to change the name